# When do we blame someone for their foolhardiness?

Tags: ethics

When do we blame someone for their foolhardiness? We might think that someone whose intentions are good are excused from its excesses. But take someone (and I hope this isn't offensive) who volunteers in a death camp or gulag hoping to stop the killing and abuse, but then gets scared and just joins in. Are they proactively seeking genocide etc., conformists, or just fools?

I think it'd be a dangerous sort of curiosity and inability to reason or be reasoned with, if not racism: so a genocidal madman fully to blame for that, but not necessarily ideologically a nazi (anymore than the other guards). Does that tell us anything about ideology?

Comment: any analogy with the use of stackexchange is merely a coincidence eh

Comment: Actions have consequences, and the amount of blame tends to depend on the magnitude of the consequences more than on the magnitude of the foolhardiness itself. I have more experience as a driver than as a cook, yet I am going to receive more blame if I cause a car accident than if I cut or burn myself while cooking.

Comment: There are different types of blame being held up here. Blame for being stupid to a culpable degree, vs blame for doing something regarded as morally wrong. Unblur that and the answer should be much clearer.

Comment: If their recklessness causes damage, then blame can be assigned. If not, then there is no reason to pass judgement.